# Can't copy files within ERX

Tags: troubleshooting, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

I use FileZilla FTP client to connect to my equipment in order to get files from there. I tried same process in my ERX, without success.
Below is a view of my directory

```
bras-2.cm#dir
Please wait...

Active/standby file systems are synchronized.

                                                               unshared
                      file                           size        size
------------------------------------------------   ---------   ---------
disk0:/incoming <DIR>                                  31744
disk0:/outgoing <DIR>                                  31744
disk0:running.cnf                                     572514      572514
disk0:GE-HDE_0_07_21_2016_17_26.dmp                 38489957    38489957
disk0:GE-HDE_0_08_09_2016_16_41.dmp                 38674861    38674861
disk0:SRP-40G+_9_SC_08_09_2016_15_48.dmp           270021233   270021233
disk0:reboot.hty                                      119104      119104
disk0:srpioahotswap.log                                  336         336
disk0:system.log                                        1539        1539
disk0:hostkey2147483649.pub                              709         709
disk0:erx40_11-2-0.rel                             239432234   239432234
disk0:srp_stats.tsa                                   777391      777391
disk0:systemHalta7_210116_142344.tsa                  406816      406816
disk0:04102013.txt                                     18383       18383
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_10_20.dmp      114688      114688
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_15_49.dmp   211566592   211566592
standby-disk0:reboot.hty                               61696       61696
standby-disk0:srpioahotswap.log                          798         798
standby-disk0:system.log                                1279        1279
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_290715_141520.tsa          617924      617924
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_280516_170017.tsa          658452      658452
                                                          date           in
                      file                           (Africa/Douala)     use
------------------------------------------------   -------------------   ---
disk0:/incoming <DIR>                              08/11/2016 16:01:50
disk0:/outgoing <DIR>                              08/11/2016 16:01:50
disk0:running.cnf                                  07/25/2012 09:25:20
disk0:GE-HDE_0_07_21_2016_17_26.dmp                07/21/2016 17:29:40
disk0:GE-HDE_0_08_09_2016_16_41.dmp                08/09/2016 16:45:32
disk0:SRP-40G+_9_SC_08_09_2016_15_48.dmp           08/09/2016 16:48:28
disk0:reboot.hty                                   08/09/2016 16:58:26
disk0:srpioahotswap.log                            08/09/2016 16:54:42
disk0:system.log                                   08/09/2016 16:55:24
disk0:hostkey2147483649.pub                        10/03/2011 05:57:24
disk0:erx40_11-2-0.rel                             08/27/2010 23:36:02    !
disk0:srp_stats.tsa                                01/12/2012 16:11:20
disk0:systemHalta7_210116_142344.tsa               01/21/2016 14:24:20
disk0:04102013.txt                                 10/04/2013 10:50:32
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_10_20.dmp   08/09/2016 11:20:40
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_15_49.dmp   08/09/2016 16:49:36
standby-disk0:reboot.hty                           08/09/2016 16:54:46
standby-disk0:srpioahotswap.log                    08/09/2016 16:54:48
standby-disk0:system.log                           01/21/2016 14:24:32
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_290715_141520.tsa       07/29/2015 14:16:10
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_280516_170017.tsa       05/28/2016 17:01:08

                  Disk capacity
                  -------------
                  Capacity      Free      Reserved
    Device        (bytes)      (bytes)    (bytes)
--------------   ----------   ---------   --------
disk0:           1024966656   363801923   68157440
standby-disk0:   1054900224   528365055   68157440
bras-2.cm#
```

Using FileZilla, I am able to see just the two sub directories named "**incoming**" and "**outgoing**"; the other files (which are my interest) are not available to me. So I had a thought to copy from the disk to the folders I can see, as you can see below

```
bras-2.cm#copy reboot.hty /incoming/reboot.hty
% Copy failed
bras-2.cm#copy reboot.hty /outgoing/reboot.hty
% Copy failed
```

It might also be useful to know the messages I get on the filezilla ftp client as I connect to my ERX

```
Status: Connecting to 41.205.0.117:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/incoming"...
Status: Directory listing of "/incoming" successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/outgoing"...
Status: Directory listing of "/outgoing" successful
Status: Creating directory '/files to get'...
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 Changed directory to "/"
Command:    MKD files to get
Response:   550 Cannot create file "files to get" or permission problem
Command:    MKD /files to get
```

So my questions are

1. Why can't I see the other files
2. Why can't I copy to the "incoming" and "outgoing" directories I see
3. Why can't I create a new directory in the disk

Below is a snapshot of the client once connected to the equipment

[image: Preview on FileZilla FTP client]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the **550 Cannot create file "files to get" or permission problem** which clearly indicates that the account you are using to connect does not have the sufficient permission.

Looking at the screenshot, on the right panel you can see the permissions set for both directories. The outgoing directory, you have no permission to write to, this includes the owner, group and other accounts.

Normally on UNIX systems, the outgoing is for read only and incoming is used to write files to the FTP server.

You can't see the other files most likely that you are not allowed to list the files, again, a permission problem.

I would investigate if there is another, perhaps a special account that allows you to view all the files. It could also be that this is done by design to protect the system from unintentionally corruption.

> The ERX system divides its vty resources among Telnet, SSH, and FTP
>   services. Each FTP session requires one vty line, and the FTP service uses
>   the authentication method configured for the vty line. If you configured
>   more than one vty line for Telnet access, the FTP service will use one of
>   those lines.

I would look which VTY line is used for FTP and make sure appropiate permissions have been configured.

But also do not forget that you can copy from the ERX to a host that runs a FTP server so this might give you better access as the ssh/telnet account you are using might have higher priviledges and you have greater control of the FTP server not being on the ERX.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: You wrote _"But also do not forget that you can copy from the ERX to a host that runs a FTP server so this might give you better access as the ssh/telnet account you are using might have higher priviledges and you have greater control of the FTP server not being on the ERX."_   **How can I do this if I want to use my PC as ftp server?**

Comment: Setup a simple FTP server on your machine and then from the other device using something like : "file copy /config/juniper.conf f t p://hostname/juniper.conf" . Look here for more copy funcitons: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos16.1/topics/reference/command-summary/file-copy.html#jd0e196  Note: I had to add spaces to f t p because the site converts it into a FTP link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I set my machine as FTP Server. in order to use the above commands?

Comment: You need to install FTP server software. This will depend on your operating system as well. If you are on Windows you can get something like FileZilla FTP server.

Comment: FTP Server installed. What next?